Aws amplify UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED on deployment
We're experiencing an issue with AWS Amplify during the deployment of our project. The sequence of events leading to the problem started when I executed amplify remove function to remove a Lambda function. The deployment then failed due to an unrelated error, but now we're encountering a specific issue related to one of our nested stacks within CloudFormation, displaying the error: "Resource handler returned message: 'No resolver found. (Service: AppSync)'."
The root stack is currently in an UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state.

However, when I check the "Resources" tab in the AWS Console, the nested stack shows a status of UPDATE_COMPLETE.

Intriguingly, upon opening the nested stack directly, its status is UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED, which seems inconsistent.

We're now in a position where we cannot deploy the latest changes, nor can we revert to a stable version of our app. Since this is affecting our production environment, simply deleting the stack isn't a viable option, as it would lead to the removal of all underlying resources.
Error from "FunctionDirectiveStack"

Does anyone have recommendations or ideas on how to resolve this problem?
